# Is there a way to create code snippets in Xcode programmatically?

Tags: xcode

Is it possible to add code snippets in Xcode for autocomplete purposes without using the UI? I auto generate some data models with scripts, and wish to enable auto complete for those.

I can see the code snippets created through Xcode under ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/CodeSnippets/, but it seems like just adding a new xml file there doesn't register it with Xcode.

Comment: Please do not add tags unrelated to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, it seems like after I add code snippets in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/CodeSnippets/, I have to kill/quit xcode explicitly for it to load the changes. If I just close and reopen xcode, the changes don't load.